# .RDLC report doesn't show on ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, .net, entity-framework-4, rdlc

I have a simple .RDLC report which does not show on it's ASPX page.  My ASPX code is:

```
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvReport" runat="server" Height="500px" Width="100%" 
    Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" 
    WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
    <LocalReport ReportPath="reports\rptAttendee.rdlc">
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

In the .cs file, I create a dataset from my Entity Framework context and convert it to a ReportData Source as follows:

```
rvReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportDataSource dataSource = new ReportDataSource("dsAttendees", attendees);
rvReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(dataSource);
rvReport.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

I have confirmed that the datasource gets created with data and the report view registers the datasource after it is added.

On the RDLC file, I created a empty datasource with the same name (dsAttendees) and exact same columns/types.  When I run the web application, the ASPX page does not show the report.  Inspecting the page, I do see the report viewer control but it's empty; even the non-databound text and the toolbar do not appear.

I suspect the issue is that the RDLC file is not picking up the datasource.  Is there a step that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but may be you should add this:

```
rvReport.Reset();
```

after

```
rvReport.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I ended up using a grid instead and writing an export for it, since the customer mostly just wanted to be able to export to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a grid instead and writing an export for the grid, since the customer mostly just wanted to be able to export to Excel.